# NSTask running a python script can't open .py file

Tags: python, xcode, macos, swift

I am creating an OS X Today Widget. To get the data I need, I am using a python script which is called by an NSTask object.

This is the code which calls the python script and displays its output:

```
func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
    let task = NSTask()
    let pipe = NSPipe()

    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/arch"
    task.arguments = ["-x86_64", "/usr/bin/python", "/Users/tomas/Developement/N_news_reader/NReader1/ahoj.py"]

    task.standardOutput = pipe

    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    var news: String = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String)!

    self.widgetLabel.stringValue = news

    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

In Terminal I have also changed ahoj.py's access rights with `chmod 777 ahoj.py`

However, after running the code, Xcode gives me following error:

*/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/tomas/Developement/N_news_reader/NReader1/ahoj.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted'*

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use sudo and place the arch command inside task.arguments

Like this :

task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sudo"
    task.arguments = ["arch", "-x86_64", "/usr/bin/python", "/Users/tomas/Developement/N_news_reader/NReader1/ahoj.py"]

It works for me as long as I change the visudo settings to avoid the "enter your password" step.